# turtle won't draw because TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm trying to draw circles given in dictionary dct and then draw lines between the circles names give as tuples in list e .

```
import turtle
e = [('A','B') , ('A','C') , ('B' , 'C')]
dct = {'A': (250.0, 0.0), 'B': (-125.0, 216.5), 'C': (-125.0, -216.50)}
for x in dct :
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(dct[x][0] , dct[x][1])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(20)
    turtle.write(x, move=False, align='left', font='Arial')
    turtle.penup()
for y in range(len(e)) :
    turtle.goto(dct[e[y][0]], dct[e[y][1]])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(dct[e[y+1][0]], dct[e[y+1][1]])
    turtle.penup()
```

**but it gives me long error the end of it is :**

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1777, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, y))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3166, in _goto
    diff = (end-start)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 263, in __sub__
    return Vec2D(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: Your second `for` loop is passing two tuples to each `.goto()` call, rather than two numbers.  It would have quickly failed with an IndexError anyway, as `e[y+1]` is out of range when `y` has its highest value.

Comment: In your first iteration, `(dct[e[y][0]], dct[e[y][1]])` is `((250.0, 0.0) (-125.0, 216.5))`. `goto` only takes one x and one y position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your second loop like so:

```
import turtle
e = [('A','B') , ('A','C') , ('B' , 'C')]
dct = {'A': (250.0, 0.0), 'B': (-125.0, 216.5), 'C': (-125.0, -216.50)}
for x in dct :
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(dct[x][0] , dct[x][1])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(20)
    turtle.write(x, move=False, align='left', font='Arial')
    turtle.penup()
for y in range(len(e)) :
    turtle.goto(dct[e[y][0]][0], dct[e[y][0]][1])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(dct[e[y][1]][0], dct[e[y][1]][1])
    turtle.penup()
```

Instead of:

```
turtle.goto(dct[e[y][0]], dct[e[y][1]])
```

and

```
turtle.goto(dct[e[y+1][0]], dct[e[y+1][1]])
```

You needed:

```
turtle.goto(dct[e[y][0]][0], dct[e[y][0]][1])
```

and

```
turtle.goto(dct[e[y][1]][0], dct[e[y][1]][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're confusing yourself by making your indexing too complicated.  Let's simplify things by deconstructing the data as part of our `for` loop and realize that we can pass either tuples or individual values to the turtle `goto()` function:

```
import turtle

RADIUS = 20

e = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A')]

dct = {
    'A': (250.0, 0.0),
    'B': (-125.0, 216.5),
    'C': (-125.0, -216.5),
}

for name, (x, y) in dct.items():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y - RADIUS)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(RADIUS)
    turtle.write(name, font='Arial')

for start, end in e:
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(dct[start])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(dct[end])

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```